# Application labels aren't unique, even though INSTALLED_APPS apps are unique

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am aware of some other questions that relate to this, however none of the other solutions seem to work. I am getting this error `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: userprofile` even though my INSTALLED_APPS array in my django settings are unique. This is my installed_apps portion

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'drf_yasg',
    'userauth',
    'userprofile'
]
```

Noting that this error did not surface at all before, when I started adding new apps it showed up, and even when I removed the new app I added it is still there. Would appreciate any guidance concerning it.

Comment: check in your individual apps folders, under apps.py that none of the `name` attributes are set to the same value as any of the other apps, or any of the externally installed apps such as `rest_framework`

Comment: checked them, all of them are unique, the name in apps.py config class follows the name of the app itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone who stumbles on this question, there might be different causes for it, mine was a `super().ready()` clause in the `on_ready()` func of the app that django says is duplicate. After diving into the source code, I found that django was using `AppConfig` for the config of this app instead of the class in apps.py. This created a duplicate with another app (for me it was `drf_yasg`) that also used `AppConfig`. I hope this helps with bringing the picture nearer.